# Accessing Kaggle tools in VM by mounting key

Tags: kaggle, vagrant-provision

I am trying to use kaggle command line tool and I am running into problems with using it inside my own vm. I downloaded the API token from the site and placed it in /.kaggle/kaggle.json on windows. My vm has ubuntu installed and in the Vagrant file I have the following:

```
config.vm.synced_folder ENV['HOME'] + "/.kaggle", "/home/ubuntu/.kaggle", mount_options: ['dmode=700,fmode=700']

config.vm.provision "shell", inline: <<-SHELL
  echo "export KAGGLE_CONFIG_DIR='/home/ubuntu/.kaggle/kaggle.json'" >> /etc/profile.d/myvar.sh
SHELL
```

when running env command in the vm I see it is correct:
KAGGLE_CONFIG_DIR=/home/ubuntu/.kaggle/kaggle.json

However, when I try to use the kaggle command for example kaggle -h I get the the following

```
(main) vagrant@dev:/home/ubuntu/.kaggle$ ls
kaggle.json
(main) vagrant@dev:/home/ubuntu/.kaggle$ kaggle -h
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/user/home/venvs/main/bin/kaggle", line 5, in <module>
    from kaggle.cli import main
  File "/user/home/venvs/main/lib/python3.7/site-packages/kaggle/__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
    api.authenticate()
  File "/user/home/venvs/main/lib/python3.7/site-packages/kaggle/api/kaggle_api_extended.py", line 149, in authenticate
    self.config_file, self.config_dir))
OSError: Could not find kaggle.json. Make sure it's located in /home/ubuntu/.kaggle/kaggle.json. Or use the environment method.
```

The paths are all correct and the file is where it should be looking for it. Anyone know what the issue could be? Is it because it is mounted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, I misread the instructions: "You can define a shell environment variable KAGGLE_CONFIG_DIR to change this location to $KAGGLE_CONFIG_DIR/kaggle.json"

So the env variable should be /home/ubuntu/.kaggle/ instead of /home/ubuntu/.kaggle/kaggle.json.